# Protected routes don't appear in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

My protected pages is not render

PrivateRouter.js code

```
import React from 'react';
import { Routes, Route, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";

const PrivateRouter = (props) => {
  const firstLogin = localStorage.getItem('firstLogin')
  return firstLogin
    ? (
      <Routes>
        <Route {...props} />
      </Routes>
    : <Navigate to="/" />
}

export default PrivateRouter
```

App.js code

```
return (
  <Router>
    <Alert />
    <input type="checkbox" id="theme" />
    <div className="App">
      <div className="main">
        {auth.token && <Header />}
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" element={auth.token ? <Home /> : <Login />} />
          <Route exact path="/register" element={<Register />} />

          <Route
            exact
            path="/:page"
            element={<PrivateRouter component={PageRender} />}
          />
          <Route
            exact
            path="/:page/:id"
            element={<PrivateRouter component={PageRender} />}
          />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </div>
  </Router>
);
```

When I go to the home page, everything happens normally, but when I try to go to the privateRouter Route, the content disappears, and only the header routes remain. as it shown in image

home.jsx
[image]

the Private route
[image]

like you see the content (h1 tag) does't appear in the private route

Answer (score 0):

The `PrivateRouter` component is rendering ***descendent*** routes, so the parent route must append a wildcard splat matcher `"*"` to its path.

```
return (
  <Router>
    <Alert />
    <input type="checkbox" id="theme" />
    <div className="App">
      <div className="main">
        {auth.token && <Header />}
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={auth.token ? <Home /> : <Login />} />
          <Route path="/register" element={<Register />} />

          <Route
            path="/:page/*" // <-- allow descendent route matching
            element={<PrivateRouter component={PageRender} />}
          />
          <Route
            path="/:page/:id/*" // <-- allow descendent route matching
            element={<PrivateRouter component={PageRender} />}
          />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </div>
  </Router>
);
```

However, this isn't the common pattern to use for protecting routed content. Update `ProtectedRouter` to render an `Outlet` instead of descendent routes, and render `PageRender` on a ***nested*** route.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Routes, Route, Navigate, Outlet } from "react-router-dom";

const PrivateRoutes = () => {
  const firstLogin = localStorage.getItem('firstLogin');
  return firstLogin ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/" replace />;
}
```

```
return (
  <Router>
    <Alert />
    <input type="checkbox" id="theme" />
    <div className="App">
      <div className="main">
        {auth.token && <Header />}
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={auth.token ? <Home /> : <Login />} />
          <Route path="/register" element={<Register />} />

          <Route path="/:page" element={<PrivateRoutes />}>
            <Route index element={<PageRender />} />
            <Route path=":id" element={<PageRender />} />
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </div>
  </Router>
);
```